# Installing IP printer on remote PC using Powershell

Tags: powershell, network-printers

I am in the process of trying to get a powershell code to work for installing an IP based printer on a remote PC.  Below is the code I have put together so far from multiple sources.  If anyone can tell me why it is not installing or help me figure out a different way to install that would be great.  If it matters I am in a win7 environment and we have powershell v5 installed

```
$PrinterIP = “192.168.100.50”
$PrinterPort = “9100”
$PrinterPortName = “IP_” + $PrinterIP
$DriverName = “Canon iR-ADV 4225/4235 PCL6”
$DriverPath = “\\myservername\Drivers\Canon\ir\Multi\x86\pcl6”
$DriverInf = “\\myservername\Drivers\Canon\ir\Multi\x86\pcl6\CNP60U.inf”
$PrinterCaption = “Copier”
$ComputerName = "Remote PC to install on"

Function CreatePrinterPort {
param ($PrinterIP, $PrinterPort, $PrinterPortName, $ComputerName)
$wmi = [wmiclass]”\\$ComputerName\root\cimv2:win32_tcpipPrinterPort”
$wmi.psbase.scope.options.enablePrivileges = $true
$Port = $wmi.createInstance()
$Port.name = $PrinterPortName
$Port.hostAddress = $PrinterIP
$Port.portNumber = $PrinterPort
$Port.SNMPEnabled = $false
$Port.Protocol = 1
$Port.put()
}

Function InstallPrinterDriver {
Param ($DriverName, $DriverPath, $DriverInf, $ComputerName)
$wmi = [wmiclass]”\\$ComputerName\Root\cimv2:Win32_PrinterDriver”
$wmi.psbase.scope.options.enablePrivileges = $true
$wmi.psbase.Scope.Options.Impersonation = `
[System.Management.ImpersonationLevel]::Impersonate
$Driver = $wmi.CreateInstance()
$Driver.Name = $DriverName
$Driver.DriverPath = $DriverPath
$Driver.InfName = $DriverInf
$wmi.AddPrinterDriver($Driver)
$wmi.Put()
}

Function CreatePrinter {
param ($PrinterCaption, $PrinterPortName, $DriverName, $ComputerName)
$wmi = ([WMIClass]”\\$ComputerName\Root\cimv2:Win32_Printer”)
$Printer = $wmi.CreateInstance()
$Printer.Caption = $PrinterCaption
$Printer.DriverName = $DriverName
$Printer.PortName = $PrinterPortName
$Printer.DeviceID = $PrinterCaption
$Printer.Put()
}

CreatePrinterPort -PrinterIP $PrinterIP -PrinterPort $PrinterPort -PrinterPortName $PrinterPortName 


InstallPrinterDriver -DriverName $DriverName -DriverPath $DriverPath -DriverInf $DriverInf 


CreatePrinter -PrinterPortName $PrinterPortName -DriverName $DriverName -PrinterCaption $PrinterCaption
```

Comment: I see a whole bunch of functions that you never show us using? How do you call this script and the functions in it?

Comment: CreatePrinterPort -PrinterIP $PrinterIP -PrinterPort $PrinterPort `
 -PrinterPortName $PrinterPortName 

 InstallPrinterDriver -DriverName $DriverName -DriverPath `
 $DriverPath -DriverInf $DriverInf 

 CreatePrinter -PrinterPortName $PrinterPortName -DriverName `
 $DriverName -PrinterCaption $PrinterCaption

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing that into the question itself. Code in comments is hard to ready.

Comment: ok updated thee question

Comment: IF there is a better way of doing this I am open to ideas.  I am just starting out on powershell so my knowledge is limited.